# Magento - Category redirect when language is changed

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I got an issue with magento and category url's when I change the language. 
When I view a category and then switch to another language it works and gives the right translated url, but when I want to change back to the default language it doesn't change the url to the right language and gives a 404. The strange thing is that it works with products but it doesn't with categories.

Does someone now what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using magento CE 1.8.1, cleared my cache often and also reindexed lots of times..

Comment: Is `Add Store Code to Urls` set `Yes` in backend? check in `admin>config>web`...

Comment: No. its value = No, should i turn it on? Since it's the same shop but only a different view

Comment: No.. Its correct... "No" is correct...